# test of angularjs controller: unsatistifed post request

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm testing an angularjs controller, using also mocks, but it raises the error 'Error: `Unsatisfied requests: POST /myurl`

My file for test contains a beforeEach method like this

```
httpBackend.whenPOST('/myurl')
     .respond( 200,obj1 );
     httpBackend.expectPOST('/myurl')


    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        $scope:scope
    });
```

and my test case is:

```
it('scope.mymethod should work fine', function(){

        httpBackend.flush()


        // verify size of array before calling the method    
        expect(scope.myobjs.length).toEqual(2)
        // call the method
        scope.saveNewPage(myobj)
        // verify size of array after calling the method
        expect(scope.myobjs.length).toEqual(3)

    })
```

The method `saveNewPage` looks like:

```
function saveNewPage(p){
    console.log('Hello')
    $http.post('/myurl', {
                e:p.e, url:p.url, name:p.name
            }).then(function (response) {
                    otherMethod(new Page(response.data.page))
                }, handleError);
}
```

Note that `console.log('Hello')` is never executed (in karma console it's never printed).

EDIT:
In the meanwhile I'm studying the doc about httpBackend, I tried to change the position of httpBackend.flush(). Basically, i'm executing a first flush(), to initialize data in the scope, then I execute the method, and then I execute an other flush() for the pending request. Specifically, in this situation the test case look like:

```
it('scope.saveNewPage  should work fine', function(){
        var p=new Object(pages[0])

        httpBackend.flush()

        httpBackend.whenPOST('/myurl',{
            url:pages[0].url,
            existingPage:new Object(pages[0]),
            name:pages[0].name
        }).respond(200,{data:pages[0]})
        httpBackend.expectPOST('/myurl')

        scope.saveNewPage(p)

        httpBackend.flush()


        expect(scope.pages.length).toBe(3)


    })
```

But now it raises `Error: No response defined !`, like if I didn't specified the mock for that url

Comment: Can you try replacing `existingPage: new Object(pages[0])` with `existingPage: p`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

- I put the calls of whenPOST and expectPOST before calling the method to test
- I put httpBackend.flush() after calling the method to test, such that, invoking the method it generates pending request, and by httpBackend.flush() it satisfies the pending requests
- I adjusted the parameter of `respond` method. Basically it didn't need to associate the response  to a `data` key of the response

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the POST is supposed to come from `saveNewPage`, you will need to call `httpBackend.flush()` between `saveNewPage` and the line where you inspect the result. `flush` only flushes the responses that have already been requested by your code.

```
it('scope.mymethod should work fine', function(){
    expect(scope.myobjs.length).toEqual(2)
    scope.saveNewPage(myobj)
    expect(scope.myobjs.length).toEqual(2)

    httpBackend.flush()
    expect(scope.myobjs.length).toEqual(3)
})
```

Comment: What does your `saveNewPage` function look like?